# git bash terminal is acting wierd in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I install oh-my-zsh in my git bash, but it is acting wierd when I use it as my vscode terminal(git bash prompt works well  with oh-my-zsh).
When I type some word, backspace, and retype some characters, it acts like below:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMOHY.png)

Some new wierd actions appear when I keep typing l and s, some [?1 appears. I keep typing f, cursor jumps to new line before line end.

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD7Jg.png)

I have raised a issue on [git bash terminal is acting wierd in vscode # 184719](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184719), and it shows more details. But I still can't solve my problem. Anyone has meet the same problem and solved it? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I update my git from 2.31 to 2.41, everything works well. If you have the same problem, you can follow [this](https://linuxhint.com/upgrade-git-latest-version-windows/) to update your git.